# Show link where the compilation error is while using IntelliJ Goland

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

currently I use Goland as IDE, it happens that sometimes when I have a compilation error then in the terminal of the IDE it's displayed the error as a link, when I click on that link it takes me to the exact line where the error is, however this behavior is not consistent, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't (the link is not displayed and only the error message is printed). So, what should I do to ensure that the link is always showed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise an issue on the official tracker, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go, and provide samples for this.

The functionality is automatic and there are no flags to configure.